# Reuse my controller actions within an Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-phone-7

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 website that can manage my budget and expenses. It's almost done. So, I have my models, my views, repositories and controllers, and these two last have some important logic, about how to find and return searches and about business logic. OK, so far so good.

But, I'd like to develop and Windows Phone 7 App where I want to make avaiable some part of the features the site will offer, so I could use the exact same controller action that the ASP.NET MVC 3 site have, but I don't have a clue about how to do it.

I never worked with WP7 development, I know it is Silverlight-based, I know a little WPF and Silverlight, but I don't know how to glue my business logic that already exist in my controllers and repositories with the app. I know I can consume Web Services with Silverlight, but then I would have duplicated logic, in my actions and services? How I can handle this? Is there any resources that can help me through this learning process?

What I want, actually, is a way to reuse everything I already have, without duplicating the logic, or, at least, make only small adjustments.

Thanks for the help and sorry if my english isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try watching the video series The Full Stack on Channel 9. In the series they build an MVC site with a WP7 companion app.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/The-Full-Stack/The-Full-Stack-Part-1-Building-the-Admin-Site-with-ASPNET-MVC-3-NuPack-and-EF-Code-First

Answer (score 1):

You should not program your business logic into your controller. Controllers are part of the user interface and setup the data for the views which are purely web based.

Therefore you cannot reuse your controllers in Silverlight, but you could use your business logic and implement a service interface for the Silverlight application which runs in the browser. If you used Entity Framework you could use the wcf services.
Before you start thinking about Silverlight you should learn XAML and WPF, then Silverlight and last but not least WP7 (which is mainly SL3 based plus some phone specific add-ons).

The other option you have: you use your web application and use the html interface on your phone 7 the same as on your webbrowser. The next release of phone 7 os supports html 5 as well.